# 12" Macbook battery health at 88% even with only 53 Load Cycles. Is this normal?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, battery, warranty

I have a 2016 12" Macbook that's only a little over a year old (and therefore out of warranty) and I'm noticing in Coconutbattery that the battery is 88.5% of it's design capacity even with only 53 load cycles.

The stats are as follows:

Design Capacity: 5550 mah

Full Charge Capacity: 4844 mah

Manufacture date: 2016-04-06

Cycle Count: 53

There's no way this can be normal. At this rate my battery will be below the 80% "bad battery" threshold within a year. I do have extended warranty coverage through my CC until November and if this is a problem I'd like to take care of it before that expires, but I know it's going to be nearly impossible to get Apple to condemn the battery as defective since it's still technically a "good" battery, even though I think a "good" battery shouldn't be showing wear like this with hardly any cycles. Should I try and pursue this with Apple or am I likely wasting my time?